# Xcode 9 : Block Based KVO Violation for observeValue function

Tags: ios, xcode, shell, swift4, key-value-observing

I’ve **SwiftLint** enabled in project and it throws an warning for below function :

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of _: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?, context _: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    . . .
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

**Shell Script Invocation Warning : Block Based KVO Violation : Prefer the new block based KVO API with key paths when using Swift 3.2 or later.**

Any fix for this?

Comment: The warning suggests the fix. However it's just a warning and harmless.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324089/swift-4-using-kvo-to-listen-to-volume-changes/46324383

Comment: This could help you https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint/issues/1989 additionally this too https://github.com/aguilarpgc/KVO

Answer (score 11):

A good tutorial to make Block Base KVO [Here](https://www.ralfebert.de/ios-examples/swift/property-key-value-observer/)

```
class CounterModel : NSObject {

    @objc dynamic var value = 0
    @objc dynamic var messages = [String]()

}


model.observe(\.value, options: [.initial]) { (model, change) in
    self.label.text = String(model.value)
}
```

Comment: Your link is broken.