# SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification stopped getting triggered on iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter, ios15

I asked and found a solution with [SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification never get triggered on iOS 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64640556/systemvolumedidchangenotification-never-get-triggered-on-ios-14). The event would be triggered and can be observed in iOS 14 with the workaround I found.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    UIApplication.shared.beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents() // <- THIS LINE

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(volumeChange(_:)), name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification"), object: nil)
}
```

However, after upgrading the system to iOS 15 the event stopped getting triggered.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This method does not work in the simulator. It only works with a real device.

Inside the ViewController class,

```
    internal var volumeValueObservation: NSKeyValueObservation?
```

Inside the ViewController life-cycle method,

```
        do {
            let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

            try audioSession.setActive(true) // <- Important
            
            volumeValueObservation = audioSession.observe(\.outputVolume) { av, _ in
                print(">>> DEBUG: [ViewController:handleVolumeChange]", av.outputVolume)
            }
        } catch {}
```

REFERENCE

[Swift 4 Using KVO to listen to volume changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46324089/swift-4-using-kvo-to-listen-to-volume-changes)

[System Volume Change Observer not working on iOS 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68249775/system-volume-change-observer-not-working-on-ios-15/68296203#68296203)

Comment: This works fine in iOS 16.3, but won't be triggered if you try to go past the minimum / maximum values.